# how does a client knows a server host/port

Tags: server, client, client-server

I made a client/server application (Basically I am defining the host and the port of the server in the client script).
I am wondering if there is a way that the client knows the hostname of the server (even if it changes, ie dynamically) 
I will appreciate to find some hints or directions, thank you

Comment: Please provide more details!

Comment: I mean if the hostname of the server is dynamic, is there any way to know the new hostname?  Tks